# Is there any non-valid contents for a referer field?

Tags: google-analytics, http-referer

I'd like to know the identities of users who come to my website by clicking on a link in my native application.

Could my app populate the referer field with a unique user ID?

Does the referer field have to be a valid URL?

Will Google Analytics handle a referer that isn't a URL?

I could mockup a URL like http://www.user.com/656  where 656 is the user ID.

Any caveats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. On one hand, i have remapped quite a few of these GA Fields (including Referral) and i have never had a problem. In addition, doing so is core functionality in GA (see below); in other words (as i am sure you know) GA actually provides its users with the templates (via **Advanced Filters**) to munge these Fields beyond recognition. [image: Advanced Filters])

On the other hand, i can think of one situation (only one actually) in which i believe Google would object and that's the case where the replacement information violates the [GA Privacy Policy](http://www.google.com/intl/en/analytics/privacyoverview.html). In particular, *displaying* or *storing* or *tracking* via GA any personally identifiable information violates the Policy [italics are mine, not a quote from the GA Privacy Policy].

The actual definition from Google:

> *Personal information is information
>   that personally identifies you, such
>   as your name, email address or billing
>   information, or other data which can
>   be reasonably linked to such
>   information*

Is a unique user ID, personally identifiable information?  There is a difference between data intended to clearly *distinguish* one user from another, and data intended to identify each user. The distinction might depend on security--i.e., how easily could someone who had in their possession a list of your unique user IDs, discover the user identifies behind them?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the referrer header just specifies a URL.  If you want to construct "fake" URLs, come up with a URI scheme specific to your application.  Something like `userid:656`.

Comment: I'm not sure who or why someone down voted you on this. It would have been helpful if they'd left a comment why. I've voted you up offset.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks, I'm not sure why they didn't leave feedback either.